# Finding recurrence relation 2 - Ternary sequences.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, recurrence-relations

for $n \ge 1$ , Let $f(n)$ be the number of ternary sequences {$0,1,2$} of length n,

that the sum of their characters are even, and they have at least one show of $0$.

How do i find the recurrence relation for f(n), thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: First note that there are $3^n$ ternary sequences of length $n$, $2^n$ of which have no $0$, so there are $3^n-2^n$ that have at least one $0$. Let $g(n)$ be the number of these whose characters have odd sum, so that $f(n)+g(n)=3^n-2^n$. Let $\sigma$ be a ternary sequence of length $n$ that has at least one $0$ and whose characters have even sum.

- If $\sigma$ ends with $2$, then removing the last character of $\sigma$ leaves a ternary sequence of length $n-1$ with at least one $0$ whose characters have even sum. Conversely, every ternary sequence of length $n-1$ with at least one $0$ whose characters have even sum can be extended to exactly one ternary sequence of length $n$ that has at least one $0$, whose characters have even sum, and that ends in $2$. This accounts for $f(n-1)$ sequences; why?
- If $\sigma$ ends with $1$, then removing the last character of $\sigma$ leaves a ternary sequence of length $n-1$ with at least one $0$ whose characters have even sum. Conversely, every ternary sequence of length $n-1$ with at least one $0$ whose characters have odd sum can be extended to exactly one ternary sequence of length $n$ that has at least one $0$, whose characters have even sum, and that ends in $1$. How many sequences of length $n$ does this account for? You can express the answer in terms of the function $g$.
- If $\sigma$ ends with $0$, then removing the last character of $\sigma$ leaves a ternary sequence of length $n-1$ whose characters have odd sum, but it might not have a $0$. How many such sequences are there that *do* have at least one $0$? To finish, you need to work out how many do *not* have at least one $0$. That will be the number of sequences of length $n-1$ that do not contain a $0$ and whose characters have even sum, which simply means that they have an even number of $1$s.

Put the pieces together and express everything in terms of $f$.

Comment: Why is $f(n)+g(n)=3^n-2^n$?

Comment: On the right hand, all the sequences with at least one 0. And on the left hand, the sequences with odd sum + sequences with even sum and at least one 0. What about odd sum and at least one 0?

Comment: So $\sigma = f(n)$ by your definitions? I'm having trouble with your explanation. Help me understand please.

Comment: @Yves: No, $\sigma$ here is simply a variable that I'm using as the name of a sequence, just as one might in some other context let $x$ be an arbitrary real number between $1$ and $3$, say. \\ $f(n)+g(n)$ is the number of sequences of length $n$ with even sum and at least one zero plus the number of sequences of length $n$ with odd sum and at least one zero, so it's simply the number of sequences of length $n$ with at least one zero.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now, will let u know if I got it soon. Thanks.

Comment: @Yves: You're welcome.

Comment: I'm getting : $f(n)=f(n-1)+3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}$ but I saw now on the other post that it's $2^{n-2}$ any idea what did I do wrong?

Comment: hey are u still around?

Comment: @Yves: It looks like you made a mistake with the last bit. The first point gives us $f(n-1)$, and the second gives us $g(n-1)$, so at that point we have $3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}$. The first part of the third point adds another $f(n-1)$. Finally, exactly half of the sequences of length $n$ that have no zeroes have an even number of ones; that adds half of $2^{n-1}$, which is $2^{n-2}$, for a total of $$f(n-1)+3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}+2^{n-2} =f(n-1)+3^{n-1}-2\cdot 2^{n-2}+2^{n-2} =f(n-1)+3^{n-1}-2^{n-2}\;.$$

Comment: I got it finally, why couldn't we say that if we know the number of sequences with at least 1 zero, then why it is not true to divide it by 2? You need to add +1 to make it right with the solution .